# Why doesn't a "where not in (select statement)" criteria return the same resault as "where (select statement > parameter)"?

Tags: sql, sql-server

This SQL statement returns no results :

```
SELECT [AutoNo], [PersonID]   
FROM [PersonTBL]
WHERE PersonID NOT IN (SELECT PersonID 
                       FROM FollowUpTBL 
                       WHERE FDate > '09/24/2014')
```

While this one returns the expected result:

```
SELECT [AutoNo], [PersonID]   
FROM [PersonTBL]
WHERE (SELECT TOP 1 FDate 
       FROM FollowUpTBL 
       WHERE FollowUpTBL.PersonID = PersonTBL.PersonID
       ORDER BY FDate DESC) < '09/24/2014'
```

I need to return all persons who has any follow-up after '09/24/2014', why does the first SQL query not work? While second query return the true data!

Is there are any way to make first query return same result (I mean use "IN (select)")?

Comment: Your first and second queries have a different date???

Comment: Sorry Sparky, but even with same date, I have no result when run first sql

Comment: The first query returns PersonID of persons without appointment after the date. ( they may have no appointment at all)
The second returns PersonID of persons where the last appointment is before the date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the glitch, The problem is because there are some FollowUpTBL records inserted with PersonID = null, So to fix the first sql query and make it work, I have to modified it as below :

```
SELECT [AutoNo], [PersonID]   
FROM [PersonTBL]
WHERE PersonID NOT IN (
    SELECT PersonID 
    FROM FollowUpTBL 
    WHERE FDate > '09/24/2014'
    and PersonID Is Not Null
)
```

So, add "and PersonID Is Not Null" fix the problem, Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

> I need to return all persons **who has** any follow-up after '09/24/2014', why first one didn't work!

Your first statement is using a `NOT IN` clause in your `WHERE` statement. This would get you exactly the opposite of what you want.

Comment: Is there are any way to make first query return same result (I mean use "IN (select)")?

Answer (score 1):

Your first query is currently written to pull any records from PersonTBL where they do NOT have an appointment after 9/24/2014. Your NOT IN should really be just an IN instead based on what you said you are looking for.